# VBA Excel - Delete the repeated values and rearrange non-repeated data line wise

Tags: excel, vba6

I am trying to organize the set of data starts from A17 to C30

| A18 (Doc. No.) | B18 (Doc. Title) | C18 (Revision) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Red | R1 |
| Monday | Red | R1 |
| Monday | Red | R1 |
| Monday | Yellow | R1 |
| Tuesday | Blue | R2 |
| Wednesday | White | R1 |
| Wednesday | White | R1 |
| Thursday | Green | R3 |

**Expected Result**

| A18 | B18 | C18 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Red | R1 |
| Tuesday | Blue | R2 |
| Wednesday | White | R1 |
| Thursday | Green | R3 |

**I cant delete or insert any row or column or filter to achieve this task. it affects all the other data.

only copy & paste is possible**

I tried below code, but I am getting stuck with rearranging the empty the datas.
because i could not delete or filter the data. I am having tuff time to achieve this. seeking your help please!

```
Sub ClearRowValues()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    ' Set the worksheet where your data is located
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("INPUT")
    
    ' Find the last row in column A with data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through rows from the bottom to the top
    For i = lastRow To 17 Step -1 ' Start from the second last row and move upwards
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws.Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            ' If the current Doc. No. is the same as the previous row, clear the current row
            ws.Cells(i, 1).ClearContents
            ws.Cells(i, 2).ClearContents
            ws.Cells(i, 3).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You could take the data into an array trough VBA or even a Dictionary Object (that would help to avoid duplicates), do what you need to do and paste the output somewhere else

Comment: can you help me out with the code please

Answer (score 1):

If copy/paste is your only option, then why not use a formula:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSEROWS(A2:C9,XMATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9)))
```

Comment: yes, that is good option, I will give a try now, but the problem is the output row is merged rows. i know its not good practive to use merge column and row. but i need to do it because for some printing usage.

Comment: @HummBird *the problem is the output row is merged rows* What do you mean with this? This solution is simple and easy if you got Excel365.

Comment: I can access only excel standard 2021 version :(

Comment: the row which I am expecting the above result is merged cells. finding trouble in getting the values with the formula you provided. and now realised that I am using excel365.